# Concurrent use of LocalDB on a network drive(s)

Tags: networking, drive, localdb

My configuration is as follows:

Server with Z: mapped to d:\something

Client with Z: mapped to \\server\
A LocalDB MDF (and the whole application) located at Z:

Either computer alone is OK, but doesn't work simultaneously. I get an exception saying
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException 0x80131904 Cannot open database z:\xxx\xxx.mdf requested by the login. the login failed.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. SQL requires than physical file attached to the database should be opened exclusively by the engine.

Solved by installing SQLEXPRESS which supports remote connections.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.  But it's not easy (did this with SQL 2016 localdb).

1. create the database locally.  The database will be created in C:\Users\ eg  `c:\Users\eric\database.mdf`
2. Close SSMS  (or disconnect from the object explorer)
3. from a command prompt:  `MSSQLLocalDB stop`
4. move the database.mdf & database_log.ldf to a network drive (eg s:\sql\database.mdf).
5. create symbolic links from the original location to new location. From a command prompt: 
   `mklink c:\Users\eric\database.mdf s:\sql\database.mdf
   mklink c:\Users\eric\database_log.ldf s:\sql\database_log.ldf`
6. `MSSQLLocalDB start`

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses having two PCs connected to the same mdf file located on a server share. That's something you can do with Access mdb files but doesn't sound possible with LocalDB.